# I can't run any script of my project without a flag and I supect it is interfering on airflow working on my python env

Tags: python, airflow, python-packaging

I'm facing an issue that, until now, was manageable. After installing a local package in my conda environment, I needed to add a flag to run any script in my project, such as a simple data extraction script:

[image: script to extract data]

Initially, it was fine; I just added the flag, and development continued. The problem started when I implemented DAGs in Airflow, and a simple command like `sh airflow dags list` stopped working:

[image: Airflow DAGs issue]

I remember this issue started after I updated my local package by running:

```bash
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

After struggling with this for an entire day, I took a break and revisited it today. I created a new environment and reinstalled Airflow, which made `airflow dags list` work as expected:

[image: Airflow working in new environment]

However, I still haven't found a solution, and I suspect it is preventing me from triggering my DAG. Could someone help?

If needed, I'm providing my `setup.py`:

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
from pathlib import Path
import os

project_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.resolve().parent.resolve().parent
presets_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.pardir, 'python'))

reqs = project_dir.joinpath("requirements.txt").read_text().splitlines()
print(project_dir.joinpath("requirements.txt"))
setup(
    name="fila-espera-pkg",
    version="v1.0.0",
    description="Module and packages used in the queue waiting project",
    long_description=project_dir.joinpath("README.md").read_text(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author="Lucas Vital",
    author_email="lucas.alves@ids.inf.br",
    license="MIT License",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=("assets", "scripts/python/notebooks")),
    install_requires=reqs,
    classifiers=[
        "Intended Audience :: Science/Research",
    ],
    package_dir={'listaespera': 'listaespera'},
    package_data={},
    zip_safe=False
)
```

---

Getting able to run my python scripts without undesired requeriment of flags and run airflow commands without any issue on my python enviornment

Comment: I suspection were confirmed,.  This issue is something related to my installation package, but I still don't know why

Comment: When you run `airflow`, what actual command is executed?  Show us the output of `which airflow` (or the equivalent of `which` for your OS if it's not linux)

Comment: I'm trying to run commads like ```airflow dags list``` and ```airflow tasks test <dag_id> <task_id> <start_date>` Airflow version is  2.7.3

Comment: Yes, I know that.  I suspect that your environment has reassigned the `airflow` command name to actually run some other command.  That's what `which` tells you.

Comment: I run then:

``sh
> (venv) lucas.alves@DES-0198:~/projects/listaespera/scripts/python$ which airflow
/home/lucas.alves/anaconda3/envs/venv/bin/airflow
```

Comment: Is that the same output you get when you run `which airflow` inside the venv that is working correctly?

Comment: yes that is the output from which command from venv enviorment. I created this env to find out why the error is happening  and I discover it is due the local package installation through  setup.py through ```pip install -e .```. For some reason using .toml instead resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have idea why, but a colleague  find that using a .toml instead of using setup.py resolves the problem. Problem it may be a bug with pip, not sure of that:

[image]

I just uninstall my local package, exclue setup.py, added the .toml and rerun
pip install -e . on project root directory and the problem was resolved.